# Determine the latest content in an email

Tags: c#, email, parsing, exchange-server-2007

The problem:

Random e-mail from different clients are received in my MS Exchange mailbox, I am not concerned with previous content rather the latest text of the message and would like to extract it.

This is currently developed as C# managed Exchange sink obtain these messages but I cannot devise a straightforward method to reliably parse it or is parsing even the correct approach?

I also don't see any property tags that give me any direction to obtain the latest text either.

Any ideas?

Thanks